# Reserving stdiin for parent process

Tags: linux, gnuplot, pipe, gnome

After several days of searching it's time to ask.  Environment is Ubuntu 12.04/Gnome.

I'm developing some embedded code on the ubuntu box and testing as much as I can in that environment before porting over to the embedded processor.  The current routine is a real time fast fourier transform and I want to use gnuplot to display the results.  So I want my test code AND gnuplot to run in the foreground at the same time and communicate via a pipe.

I did the usual popen() call and that worked except for one thing.  stdin for the child (gnuplot) is still attached to the console.  It is in contention with the parent process.  The parent process needs to receive keystrokes to modify its behaviour.  Sometimes the parent gets the keystroke and sometimes gnuplot does.

So I've tried the fork/exec path.  Specifically

```
        pid_t pg = tcgetpgrp(1);    // get process group associated with stdout
        cerr << "pid_t pg = " << pg << endl;
        cerr << "process pid is " << getpid() << endl;

        if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {// open the pipe
            cerr << "pipe failure" << endl;
            exit(3);
        } // if pipe

        cpid = fork();
        if (cpid == -1) {
            cerr << "fork failure" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        if (cpid == 0)  {   // this is the child process

            if (tcsetpgrp(1, pg) == -1) {           // this should set the process associated with stdin (gnuplot) with the
                cerr << "tcsetgrp failed" << endl;  // foreground terminal.
                exit(7);
            }

            close(pipefd[1]);    // close child's writing handle

            if (pipefd[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {    // this changes the file descripter of stdin back to 0
                if ( dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO) {
                    cerr << "dup2 error on stdin" << endl;
                    exit(6);
                }
            }


            if (execl("/usr/bin/gnuplot", "gnuplot", "-background", "white", "-raise", (char *) NULL)) {                
                cerr << "execl failed" << endl;
                exit(2);
            }  else // if exec
                close(pipefd[0]);   // close parent's reading handle

        } // if cpid


        // back in parent process
```

This fires off gnuplot as I expect it should.  I can see gnuplot consuming all the resources of one core as it normally does.  The problem is that no graph appears on the screen.

So my question is, how do I start a child process, totally detach it from the console so it won't get any keystrokes and get the output of gnuplot to display?

Comment: we used popen for such a task successfully 15 years ago and it was quite simple IIRC. we had a c++ program doing some expensive fitting. it called popen to open a pipe, sent gnuplot commands there and multiple x11 terminals with our graphs popped up and showed intermediate results while the fitting went on. there's no reason why the pipe should receive other input than what you send to the file descriptor you receive from the popen call.